# Kendo UI Mobile - Stop fixed header from registering in click event of listview

Tags: jquery, listview, kendo-ui

I currently have an issue where a fixed header registers in my listview's click event.

I know this is probably expected behavior, but was curious as to the best method of excluding it from the logic within my click event? I know the fixed header uses the class `km-group-title`

The DOM reads like this:

```
<li>
    <div class="km-group-title">...</div>
    <ul class="km-list">
        <li>...</li>
    <ul>
</li>
```

Not registering that div tag is what i want.

Thank you

Update:

Here is a snippet of how I'm binding my click event (I think I just solved my question by the conditional logic but if there is a better way please let me know!):

```
$("#mList").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data: source, group: [ {field: "letter", dir: "asc"} ]}),
        template: $("#mTemplate").html(),
        headerTemplate: "${value}",
        fixedHeaders: true,
        type: "group",

        click: function(e) {
            // only register list items which contain an anchor tag
            if (e.target.closest("a").length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // do something with list item
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Where is the code of your click event? How do you subscribe to it?

Comment: OP updated with relevant code.